# How can I get the checked checkbox values using MVVM?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, checkbox

Right now, I'm working on a WPF project.

I have a confirmation dialog that displays a list of repeated strings that the user imported from a CSV file.

The user can check off the repeated strings they want to add to a list (listview) and click ok.

The problem is I'm not sure how to get the value of the checkbox items that are checked off and add them to a list. How do I know what checkbox is selected and add the selected items to a list?

I want to do this task using MVVM and not code behind. I've seen a few examples using code behind and they still confuse me.

I think I have to use commands but I'm not sure still how to get the selected checkbox value?

Here's my attempt:

Code in ViewModel:

```
private bool isSelected;
    public bool IsSelected
    {

        get
        {

            return isSelected;
        }

        set
        {

            isSelected = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("IsSelected");

            if (IsSelected == true)
            {

                foreach (var item in confirmationList.PassList)
                {

                    List.Add(item);
                }

                RaisePropertyChanged(LIST);

            }

            else if (IsSelected == false)
            {

            }
        }
    }
```

XAML:

```
<Grid>
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Inventory}">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                         <CheckBox Content="{Binding}" IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>

            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}"
                            Header="Name">
            </GridViewColumn>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Not sure what else to do from here to get the checked off values?

EDIT: updated xaml to reflect look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start by defining a model class

```
 public class ListModel
 {
     public string Data { get; set; }
     public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
 }
```

Then Bind the list of this model to the Listview's ItemsSource

```
List<ListModel> data = new List<ListModel>();
```

modify the binding of your check box to

```
<CheckBox Content="{Binding Data}" IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay"/>
```

then when you need to retrieve you may execute the following linq to get all selected strings

```
IEnumerable<String> selectedData = data.Where(d => d.IsSelected).Select(d => d.Data);
```

now you'll have all the data which is selected in the UI in the field selectedData

Comment: Do I need a model class? What if my list is just List<string> Inside of my viewmodels? I'm having trouble though with List<string>. It says, 'string' does not contain a definition for 'IsSelected' and no extension method 'IsSelected' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: if you do not prefer to hava data class then perhasp it woulld be difficult to bind a single isselected property from view model to the checkboxex which represnts your list of strings. you can make use of converters for same, but in that case you may have to write a converter class.

Comment: Use ObservableCollection instead of List

Answer (score 0):

A excellent way is create a new class, because when you must bind the properties into Grid, ItemsControl or other element that it use ItemsSource is easier.

In your model, the class will be...

```
public class ListModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool isSelected;
    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get { return isSelected; }
        set
        {
            if (isSelected != value)
            {
                isSelected = value;
                if (PropertyChanged != null)
                {
                    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("IsSelected"));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You binding this property to CheckBox

```
<ItemsControl  ItemsSource="{Binding ListModelBinding, Mode=TwoWay}">
     <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
</ItemsControl>
```

In your ViewModel

```
private ObservableCollection<ListModel> _listModelBinding;
public ObservableCollection<ListModel> ListModelBinding
    {
        get { return _listModelBinding; }
        set { _listModelBinding= value; RaisePropertyChanged("ListModelBinding"); }
    }
```

The solution serve several items. If you only one property, simply create a bool property like I created  ListModelBinding in ViewModel, and after you bind this property to CheckBox in xaml.

When you want retrieve data only apply  Linq in ListModelBinding and that's it.