# how to get combobox checkbox checked values in c# using wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

```
                <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <CheckBox 

                     Style="{StaticResource CheckBoxStyle}" 

                     Content="{Binding CDM_VALUE1}" CommandParameter="{Binding}"  

                     Command="{Binding ElementName=MyWindow, Path=DataContext.SetSelectAllCommand}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
```

i have given here in checkbox as item template

Comment: Why is the question flagged for vb.net when you are asking for c#?

Answer (score 0):

you need to add parameter IsChecked in your XAML code

```
IsChecked="{Binding Path=SetSelectAllCommand, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

this link may help you [How can I get the checked checkbox values using MVVM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24215649/how-can-i-get-the-checked-checkbox-values-using-mvvm)